# githubにて.ipynbファイルが表示されません。

Tags: python, github

githubのprivate repositoryに、jupyter notebookの.ipynbファイルを置いています。

githubでは、jupyter notebookのブラウザ表示同様のレンダリングがサポートされているようですが、

"Sorry, something went wrong. Reload?"のメッセージが出るのみで、

.ipynbファイルをレンダリングしてくれません。

生ソースでの表示はできるのですが、なぜでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

おそらくGitHub側の問題で、対処はできないのではないかと思います。

[このページ](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3555)を見ると、多くの人が同じ問題に遭遇していると報告しています。一時的な問題の可能性があり、しばらくしてからロードすると問題なく表示されるかもしれません。